# Git commit fails with no error

Tags: git, osx-mavericks, git-commit

I keep pulling these commands

```
Macintosh:project david$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   cloud-hosting.html
#   modified:   complete-package.html
#   modified:   css/hosting-1.0.css
#   modified:   css/slider.css
#   new file:   domains.html
#   modified:   index.html
#   modified:   js/bootstrap-slider.js
#
Macintosh:project david$ git commit -m 'test git commit because git is broken' .
Macintosh:project david$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   cloud-hosting.html
#   modified:   complete-package.html
#   modified:   css/hosting-1.0.css
#   modified:   css/slider.css
#   new file:   domains.html
#   modified:   index.html
#   modified:   js/bootstrap-slider.js
#
```

including every different permutation on `git commit` that I could find and nothing will let me `git push` - because it says 'everything up to date'.

I've tried GUI clients that say everything from 'a git error occurred' to 'git error: (null)' I don't even know how to get any further diagnostic information about my git actions...!

In terms of a 'clean system' I'm far from that, and I think this might have something to do with it -- I recently upgraded to mavericks, changed over my Xcode implementation and upgraded Xcode command line tools because Coda needed it (it couldn't find my old git client)

Does changing your git client change anything? (Should it)

Thanks

Comment: have you tried doing an update? Have you tried checking out to a new location, manually transferring modified files to new location and committing from there?

Comment: Have you tried to 'git add' the files before committing them? Using "git commit ." won't commit anything if you're in the wrong directory. It should work if you're in the root of the directory though..

Comment: I don't know what an update is -- but as soon as I posted this question I realised I could do exactly that; a clone and remodification of all files as yet uncommitted. This worked but the old local repository is seriously corrupted... I guess the fact that you can do that is due to the power of git and its distributed nature.

Comment: Also, yes I did run a git add from the root of the directory. Git diff outputted nothing

Comment: After a `git add`, a `git diff` without further arguments would show nothing, as it defaults to show the index-worktree difference (which is null after youve added all changes). You would have to do `git diff --staged` to see your staged changes.

Comment: Seeing how recloning fixed your problem (which seems to have been a corrupted repo), please describe your findings in an answer (not a comment!) below, so that other people with similar situations know what to look for; and also so that your question gets marked "answered" ;)

Comment: Thanks for that (and yeah I felt like git diff needed a few more arguments than that; though unfortunately git isn't my first language). In respect of comments vs answers I promise you that every time I answer my own question I never know whether it's more 'correct' to comment or answer. Maybe there is no authoritatively correct and proven optimal solution to this problem. But that is an architectural question about the fabric of stack overflow itself. However we've digressed now, haven't we

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a case of a corrupted repo caused by either

a) Upgrading to mavericks and its subsequent upgrade of Xcode
b) The Xcode upgrade incurred a few hiccups through its upgrade in itself as my RAM was corrupt and causing hourly kernel panics, just after my mavericks upgrade
c) Then, Coda 2 asked to reinstall Xcode command line tools, as it was experiencing a known issue where this was the fix. To cap it all off, I cancelled this download once because I was on a bus and my iPhone internet coverage was poor.
d) Definitely my git binary and probably my git version changed throughout this process, and it was a long time since my last commit to that repository.

Definitely a corrupted repository, as confirmed by the reclone and remodification which worked.

In terms of repeatability, I don't think this will come up ever due to the highly idiosyncratic circumstances. I think we can mark this one as an anomalous case, and reaffirm our faith in git.

In git we trust.